# Parsing Non-Uniform Data from a txt Document to place into Database

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very large document that I'm trying to parse the information out and place it into a database. The information is semi-organized into manageable chunks, and the numbers separated by the pipes will always be the same quantity (in this case 3).

```
000000&V-1 some text
1|2|3 A form
4|5|6 B form
000000&V-2 different text
7|8|9 C form
10|11|12 D form
13|14|15 E form
16|17|18 F form
000000&V-3 more different text
19|20|21 G form
000000&V-4 some more text
22|23|24 H form
25|26|27 I form
```

Using PHP, I know how to enter the data into the database from the array(s) that I will be getting as a result, I just don't know how to parse the sections to get what I want using PHP.

I need to retrieve the number after the `000000&V-`, then the text string, then all the numbers and form letter and put into an array, like so:

```
{1, some text, 1, A}  
{1, some text, 2, A}
{1, some text, 3, A}
{1, some text, 4, B}
{1, some text, 5, B}
{1, some text, 6, B}
{2, different text, 7, C}
{2, different text, 8, C}
{2, different text, 9, C}
{2, different text, 10, D}
....ETC!
```

Comment: It sounds like you're going to become very familiar with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some loops alongside with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions:

```
$firstColumn = null;
$secondColumn = null;
$separator = '/000000\&V\-(\d+)\s(.+)/';

$result = [];
foreach ($contents as $line) {
    // Retrieve current first and second columns values from separator.
    if (preg_match($separator, $line, $matches)) {
        $firstColumn = $matches[1];
        $secondColumn = $matches[2];
        continue;
    }

    // If we here, the current line is not a separator, so get numbers
    // and letter from it.
    list($numbers, $letter, $_) = explode(' ', $line);

    // // Cool functional style
    // $result = array_merge($result, array_reduce(
    //     explode('|', $numbers),
    //     function ($carry, $number) use ($firstColumn, $secondColumn, $letter) {
    //         $carry[] = [$firstColumn, $secondColumn, $number, $letter];
    //         return $carry;
    //     },
    //     []
    // ));

    // "Bad" nested loops style
    // Explode numbers and add record for each number into the result.
    foreach (explode('|', $numbers) as $number) {
        $result[] = [$firstColumn, $secondColumn, $number, $letter];
    }
}
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31d5be96256686d08eed82c92b7348bc36a74151).

Comment: wow! thank you so much for doing this! I was expecting some starting points, and maybe some insults, but you went above and beyond with this answer. thank you!

Comment: @thatGuy, add `+` after `\d` in regex: `'/000000\&V\-(\d+)\s(.+)/'`

Comment: thanks again! I don't know if it's technically correct, but I also used ([0-9]+) as a solution.

Comment: @thatGuy, `\d` is an alias for `[0-9]`. So you have used the right thing, only used different naming.